# Trying to connect with local database using Prolog and ODBC

Tags: prolog, odbc

I'm trying to make a connection from a Prolog program to my local database using ODBC.

This is my code:

```
use_odbc :- open_wordnet,
            disconnect_database().

open_wordnet :- odbc_connect('Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;', _,
                [ user(''),
                password(''),
                alias(myDB),
                open(once)
                ]).

disconnect_database() :- odbc_disconnect(myDB).
```

And this is the error I get when I try to execute my code:

```
ERROR: ODBC: State S1090: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
```

Does anyone know the origin of my problem? Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution! I was missing the ODBC Driver to my database, once I configured my driver I was able to connect just fine.